# How to show the results when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
<form id="F2" onsubmit="return false;">
Which do you want?<br />
<input name="a" onclick="TotalCheckedValues()" type="checkbox" value="10" />New (10.00)<br />
<input name="b" onclick="TotalCheckedValues()" type="checkbox" value="0" />Broken (Free)<br />
<input name="c" onclick="TotalCheckedValues()" type="checkbox" value="55" />Antique (55.00)<br />
<input name="d" onclick="TotalCheckedValues()" type="checkbox" value="4.95" />Refurbished (4.95)<br />
Total: <input name="T" readonly="readonly" size="5" type="text" /><br />
<input onclick="TotalCheckedValues()" type="button" value="Click" />&nbsp;</form>


function TotalCheckedValues() {
var total = 0;
if(document.getElementById("F2").a.checked == true) { total +=     parseFloat(document.getElementById("F2").a.value); }
if(document.getElementById("F2").b.checked == true) { total += parseFloat(document.getElementById("F2").b.value); }
if(document.getElementById("F2").c.checked == true) { total += parseFloat(document.getElementById("F2").c.value); }
if(document.getElementById("F2").d.checked == true) { total += parseFloat(document.getElementById("F2").d.value); }
var ts = new String(total);
if(ts.indexOf('.') < 0) { ts += '.00'; }
if(ts.indexOf('.') == (ts.length - 2)) { ts += '0'; }
document.getElementById("F2").T.value = ts;
document.getElementById("F3").innerHTML = ts;
}
```

I want to show the updated result whenever I click and untick the checkbox.

Comment: What actually is happening? IS there a error? Please tell in detail.

Comment: No there is no error. I want to show the result in multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "script" tag in your html before function start which indicate javascripts code.